# HTTP Outbound Gateway - RestTemplate that depends on Message

Tags: spring-integration-http

I would like to configure the RestTemplate that will be used by the HTTP Outbound Gateway based on the Message (e.g. get authentication information from the payload). Is there a way to achieve this, preferably with Java DSL?

The API seems to allow a configurable URI based on the Message, but what about the RestTemplate?

Comment: Please share your code by editing the question. What have you tried since now?

Comment: The question is not about errors I am getting in my code; it is about API capabilities. There is no code as I cannot find the proper API call - if it exists.